# Move data from multiple columns into one and remove duplicates

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, power-query

I currently have a situation wherein I require the unique data from multiple columns to be moved/identified in one single column.

The data currently looks like this:

| Apple | Microsoft | Dell |
| --- | --- | --- |
| U.S | U.S | France |
| France | India | China |
| Germany | Mexico | Thailand |
| Australia |  |  |

Final result required:

| Apple |
| --- |
| U.S |
| France |
| Germany |
| Australia |
| India |
| Mexico |
| China |
| Thailand |

The data is split into multiple columns (~40-50) with a maximum of 200-300 datapoints in each column, so the number of available rows where the data is to be pasted shouldn't be an issue.

I did find this solution which refers to power query ([How to move all data to one column](https://superuser.com/questions/1426370/how-to-move-all-data-to-one-column)), but I need to automate this entire process. Appreciate any help!

Comment: Welcome! Please see [**this topic**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62769255/getting-unique-values-using-dictionary-would-like-to-understand-more) (and many others that will give a quick search on the string ***vba dictionary unique values***)

Comment: the solution you've linked seems to be scalable. What you need to do is just replace your original data, convert it to a table (making sure table name is the same as before) and running Power Query again (not setup, just refresh). Have you tried it?

Comment: Moreover, all the actions that @MátéJuhász listed in his comment, you can record with a macro recorder and perform from one click.

Comment: What do you mean by **automate this entire process**?  What exactly is wrong with the PQ solution you reference?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a newer version of Excel, use UNIQUE after "unwrapping" the columns with INDEX. Starting in say D2:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$C$5,MOD(ROW()-ROW($D$2),4)+1,TRUNC((ROW()-ROW($D$2))/4)+1)
```

which will put each column below the other in column D, including duplicates and blanks. Then in say E2:

```
=UNIQUE(D2:D13)
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the **Range**- go to **Data**- **From Table/Range**- check the option **My table has headers** and click **OK**- import the range to Power Query editor:

[image]

Select all columns- go to **Transform** tab- select **Unpivot Columns**:

[image]

Change the **Value** column name to **Apple**- Right click the Apple column and select **Remove Duplicates**- Remove Attribute column:

[image]

Go to Home- Close & Load:

[image]

[image]